# SAML Token for webservices

Tags: weblogic, security, saml

I want to implement SAML Token based authentication and authorization for a Web services in Java to be deployed on WEBLOGIC 11g Server?

I need a suggestion on some good online resources or help which would help me implement it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[OpenSAML](https://spaces.internet2.edu/display/OpenSAML/Home) would be a good place to start.  The Java version is full featured, and it has extensive documentation that guides you through its usage: https://spaces.internet2.edu/display/OpenSAML/OSTwoUserManual

Comment: Hi Scott, thanks for this link, this really looks cool with a lot of example code. For now I am trying to implement SAML 2.0 token feature for the web services to be deployed on weblogic. Trying to see if I can resolve it.